# JFreechart Label too small

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jfreechart

I am creating a new view for an eclipse rcp plugin. In this view i want to use a JFreeChart horizontal(!) StackedBar with a fix height of 20. The problem is, that the item labels are displayed too small, although there is much space to be displayed larger (see picture) Setting a larger size with "setSeriesItemLabelFont()" will not increase the high of the label but only the width

Picture:

[image]

Here is my code:
The ViewPart:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    parent.setLayout(gridLayout);

    totalRenderingContent = new TotalRenderingContent(parent);
}
```

and TotalRenderingContent.java

```
public TotalRenderingContent(Composite parent) {

    chartComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
    GridData gridDataChart = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false);
    gridDataChart.heightHint = 20;
    chartComposite.setLayoutData(gridDataChart);
    chartFrame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(chartComposite);
    createTotalRenderingContent();
}

private void createTotalRenderingContent() {
    Chart renderingChart = new TotalRenderingChart();
    JFreeChart chart = renderingChart.getChart();
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartFrame.add(chartPanel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using SWT_AWT, perhaps this is the problem. There is org.jfree.experimental.chart.swt.ChartComposite, which helps to display charts in SWT. Look at the example: http://codeandme.blogspot.ru/2012/12/using-jfreechart-in-your-rcp.html